# Adding a file to Intellij automatically ignores it in version control

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

When I try to add a file to a project, it shows up as `"Olive"` ([Ignored by VCS](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html)). I have tried several things to get `IntelliJ` to recognize this file for `VCS`, without success:

1. Ensure the file was not listed or masked under Configure Ignored Files
2. Attempted to add the file to `VCS` via `Subversion` -> Add to `VCS`
3. Delete project and re-checkout
4. Invalidate `IntelliJ` `Cache` and restart

For the record, adding a new file to another project works as expected and another co-worker is having the exact same issue on his machine so it feels project related. I'm just not sure where to look at this point.

Comment: I (and my colleagues in project) have the same issue. Have you solved it? If so, could you please answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and had a hard time finding the solution.

New files from a modules kept getting auto ignored, while other modules worked fine.
Checked IntelliJ ignore list and all I had there were the maven target folders

IntelliJ seems to hold its own ignore list, separate from the svn client, but at the same time, applies the ignore rules from the svn client.

I am using IntelliJ with an old tortoiseSVN installation(where I must have ignored something the wrong way). I used the command line to check what ignore list I had there.

1. Go to the root folder of the module
2. Use `svn pl` to get the list of properties set for the folder
3. Check `svn:global-ignores` (and `svn:ignore`, if you have it) with `svn pg prop name`
   I had a line with the `*` which means ignore everything.
   Didn't have an editor to use `svn pe`, so I deleted global-ignores property from that folder. After this, IntelliJ gave me the prompt to add the newly created files to svn, and no longer automatically ignored it

Late answer but hope it helps someone else.